# UploadDataAsync or UploadFileAsync to server with progress

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, file-upload, client-server

My code is supposed to upload a zip file to the server from the users computer and update a progress bar while it's uploading.  It is successful at uploading the zip file, however, the web page waits till it is finished.  Only when it is finished does it do one update to say its complete.  It seems to be passing all the bytes of data before updating.  I would use `UploadFileAsync()` , however, it is not working with `FileUpload.PostedFile.FileName` When I upload the bytes by sending the PostedFile to a `byte[]` and using the `UploadDataAsync()` it works properly.

This is the code to start the upload in a thread:  ***(THIS UPLOADS TO THE SERVER CORRECTLY WITHOUT PROGRESS)***

```
byte[] bbb = fileMiscUploadPath.FileBytes;

 WebClient client = new WebClient();
 Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
 {
      client.UploadProgressChanged += new UploadProgressChangedEventHandler(client_UploadProgressChanged);
      client.UploadDataCompleted += new UploadDataCompletedEventHandler(client_UploadFileCompleted);
      client.UploadDataAsync(new Uri(UploadLocation), bbb);
 });
 thread.Name = "AAAUpload";
 thread.Start();
```

I have even tried to use the `UploadFileAsync()` method and it works on my local machine but it doesn't work when I publish it to the server and then try to upload the file.  This is the version with UploadFileAsync():  **(THIS FAILS TO UPLOAD AT ALL ON THE SERVER, HOWEVER IT DOES UPLOAD WITH A PROGRESS BAR WHEN RUNNING LOCALY)**

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
{
     client.UploadProgressChanged += new UploadProgressChangedEventHandler(client_UploadProgressChanged);
     client.UploadFileCompleted += new UploadFileCompletedEventHandler(client_UploadFileCompleted);
     client.UploadFileAsync(new Uri(UploadLocation), fileMiscUploadPath.PostedFile.FileName.ToString());

 });
 thread.Name = "AAAUpload";
 thread.IsBackground = true;
 thread.Start();
```

Here is the clent_UploadProgressChanged function:

```
void client_UploadProgressChanged(object sender, UploadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    byteHasBeenUploaded = true;
    try
    {
        double bytesIn = double.Parse(e.BytesSent.ToString());
        double totalBytes = double.Parse(e.TotalBytesToSend.ToString());
        double percentage = bytesIn / totalBytes * 100;
        UploadPercent = int.Parse(Math.Truncate(percentage).ToString());
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        UploadPercent = 999;
    }
}
```

It does hit the method, however, it only happens once when it is finished. Is there a way to change the buffer when using `UploadDataAsync()`?  How can I break up the bytes so the `UploadProgressChanged()` method is triggered more than once?

These are the values of `UploadProgressChangedArgs` when running it with `UploadDataAsync()`:
[image: Values of UploadProgressChangedEventArgs e]

Comment: Async methods are notoriously hard to debug
I'm going to guess that there is an exception thrown in your UploadProgressChanged when running o the server?
try to catch (capture) the exception when running on the server (write it to a file or something).

Comment: It is not returning any exceptions.

Comment: There should be no need to make the `async` calls from a background thread as they are non blocking and return immediately. Using a `Thread` like this will also cause the event handlers to [run on thread pool threads](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7135052/on-which-threads-does-webclient-raise-its-events), which is generally not workable if updating a UI (this may be irrelevant depending on the context)